# How to convert 3D skeltal data to Euler representation like Kinect?

Tags: kinect, motion, inverse-kinematics

The CMU motion capture data stored the skeleton of each frame as Euler angles. It is easy to convert the Euler angles to 3D points by using [Mocap Toolbox](https://github.com/lawrennd/mocap). But I wondered how to do the inverse operation? It seems like the Kinect has the same operation: firstly obtained the 3D coordinates of human from the depth camera; secondly, stored these coordinates as Euler angles.

[image: Question Image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Motion Builder can convert the C3D dataset into BVH formats. It is exactly what I want. I am going to exploit the programming methods to achieve that.